# Expect script not sending new line correctly

Tags: shell, keyboard, newline, expect

I'm using expect to respond to a network service.  However, I've noticed in Wireshark, when I do the following:

```
send "mystring\r\n"
```

it gets translated on the wire to:

> "mystring\n"

I've tried setting `stty raw`, and various combinations of `\r`, `\n`, as well as sending ASCII codes from within expect.  Expect seems to be translating any of these combinations to `\n`.  The problem is the server seems to require a `\r\n` in order to accept the input.  I've been able to determine this, because when I use "interact" from within expect, and then type a `^M` (control-v enter) from the shell, Wireshark sees a string of:

> "mystring \r\n"

sent out over the wire, and the server processes the input correctly.  Is there a way to properly send this combination through expect without the translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing the `stty` directly or by using `set stty_init raw` in the `expect` script?  (`expect`'s `stty` command operates on *your* terminal, not the pty.)  You may also want to look at the `-nottyinit` option to `spawn`.

Comment: Ah...  within my script, I do:

stty raw

I missed stty_init on the man page.  I'll give it a try tomorrow and see how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: So, I was able to resolve the issue.  I had to use `set stty_init raw` prior to spawning my command.  In addition, I also had to send the `\r\n` in hex: `send "mystring\x0d\x0a"`.  That did the trick.

Comment: How on earth did you figure out to send hex chars?  Working for me as well, but surely there's a better solution than this?

Comment: That worked but now newlines don't get rendered correclty :(